# Show that $f(x,y)= xy^3+e^{xy}$ is directional differentiable in any direction

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

> The function $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined by 
>   $$f(x,y)= xy^3+e^{xy}$$ Show that $f$ is directional differentiable in
>   any direction $v\in \mathbb R^2$ in the point $(1,1)$ and give the
>   formula for $D_vf(1,1)$

I thought I could use that it is directional differentiable if 
$$lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\xi+tv)-f(\xi)}{t}$$
exists.

So that's what I tried to show, but I got stuck.
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\xi+tv)-f(\xi)}{t}=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+tv_1)(1+tv_2)^3+e^{(1+tv_1)(1+tv_2)}-1-e}{t} = 0$$

But that would also mean that $D_vf(1,1)=0$, which felt kind of wrong. Am I using the definition wrong?

**Edit**
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+tv_1)(1+tv_2)^3+e^{(1+tv_1)(1+tv_2)}-1-e}{t} = v_1(1+e)+v_2(3+e)$$

Comment: How did you get that the limit is $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+tv_1)(1+tv_2)^3+e^{(1+tv_1)(1+tv_2)}-1-e}{t} = 0$ is not correct !

Comment: I see I made a mistake calculating that, I tried it again. Would that be the final answer now?

Comment: Yes, $ v_1(1+e)+v_2(3+e)$ is correct.